# Error while trying to setup AngularFire on an Angular project

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to set up AngularFire for a new Angular project.

I followed the official documentation [there](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md) but I am constantly getting the following error:

> FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

---

Please find below the code I run (same as doc):

1. app.component.ts

```
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Firestore, collection, collectionData } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore)
  items$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor() {
    const aCollection = collection(this.firestore, 'items')
    this.items$ = collectionData(aCollection);
  }
}
```

2. app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { initializeApp,provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { provideAuth,getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideFirestore,getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

Here is what I checked:

- collection() is well imported at the top of *app.component.ts* (same as doc)
- the first argument of collection() is "this.firestore" which refers to line 11 : `firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore)` (same as doc)
- the firebase variable in the *environment.ts* file seems correct
- I installed AngularFire with the Angular CLI's command: `ng add @angular/fire`
- I checked versions I installed:

  - Angular CLI: 16.0.6
  - @angular/fire: 7.6.1
- *app.module.ts* seems correct

---

Your help in solving this mystery would be much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: It looks completely right to me, maybe try npm install, just in case there is a package version missmatch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it did not work.
I also found this thread on GitHub for the same issue : 
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3422